# storing arrays as value in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called product attribute in which I want to store products attribute name and its value one by one. For example of user selected price as attribute name and 100,200,300 as its values then I want to store price with 100, 200 and 300 with product id. I've array like this:-

```
[attribute_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Color
            [1] => weight
            [2] => Brand
            [3] => Price
        )

[Attrvalue] => Array
    (
        [0] => Black
        [1] => 2kg
        [2] => 3kg
        [3] => 4kg
        [4] => Sony
        [5] => Samsung
        [6] => LG
        [7] => 500
        [8] => 1000
        [9] => 2000
        [10] => 9000
        [11] => 9500
        [12] => 10000
    )
```

How to devide this array in key value pair like for color=>Black in php?

Comment: I got a question. For that code fragment you shown, how did you end up with it in the first place? It's unnatural to me. Normally, the values that are to be stored in a database come direct from user input and then imported into PHP code via the special `$_GET` and `$_POST` global arrays and then the values are inserted into the table as one row.

Comment: I am getting this array in $_POST parameter after submitting the form. I want to store in db like Color:Black,Weight:2kg,Weight:3kg,weight:3kg.... and so on. These are two array variables from the from

Comment: Confused...can u eloborate on what is content in array n how you want to insert into db ?

Comment: I assume you'll have some repeating data. You should normalize the data and make a few tables. For example, if two different items have a choice of three weights that are the same and another two different items have a choice of two duplicate weights, then you would be better off making a separate table for weights and one for items. Why not elaborate more on the data so we can figure something out.

Answer (score 1):

You can name your form inputs like this attr[attrname] eg
for single value attr
     
for mutiple value attr use

```
<select name="attr['price'][]" multiple>
<option>...</option>
</select>
```

This will provide you an array like

```
array('attr'
           =>array('color'=>value),
           =>array(
                  'price'=>array(
                                 0=>value1,
                                 1=>value2
                                 )
                  )
);
```

Comment: Thanks very much Dude. It Solved My Problem. I was thinkin about this and you gave me the correct answer. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($data as $key=>$value)
```

{
    $keys = "'".implode("',' ", $temp_tablev)."'";

```
$values = "'".implode("',' ", $temp_tablev)."'";
```

}

$sql = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO ($keys) VLAUES ($values)") or die(mysqli_error());

Comment: Thakns Rao for reply. I've used the solution given by user3774708 after forming array like user3774708 mentioned. I've just used two foreach and i am sucessfully able to insert the desired record in database. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a data structure that is handy in PHP, but mysql does not need to see the details, use json_encode and json_decode.  Then put the result in a TEXT column.

Comment: It is simple form submit which does not required json encode and decode.Thanks for your reply.